# Is Light Bitcoin a legitimate site or a SCAM?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability, mining-reward

Is light Bitcoin a legitimate Mining site or another SCAM?

Answer (score 4):

There is no mention that they are doing mining at all, nor a figure for their current mining power, or blocks that they found, just some vague explanations that they are investing any deposits and promises of large gains. 
It actually looks like they are incorporated to a superficial check, the certificate of incorporation does lead to a gov.uk site that lists the company and other companies that I'm aware off.

So:

- No mining
- Large featuring of referral rewards
- Vague business plan
- No mention of the owners or team

I'd treat it as a scam until palpable evidence of the contrary is presented.

Comment: The office of this 'long term, stable' company? It's some guy's flat. https://www.google.com/maps/place/23+Hoyle+Mill+Rd,+Barnsley+S70+3EL,+UK Also, the company was incorporated Nov 2016.

Answer (score 3):

Don't expect to make easy money using HYIP(high risk yield products) similar to what you mentioned. Most of them are anonymous and cannot be traced to an actual individual which leads to the conclusion that they are scared/concerned about getting caught. They do not seem to have proof of running a mining operation aswell.

Stay safe.

Answer (score 0):

Treat as a scam, and try your best to get your coins back
And ID and personal data theft!

Recently I am a victim of lginn.com fake trading website, yes, I am brand new to Crypto and I lost everything! and suckered in but an Asian girl after 2 1/2 months she blocked me

Said her name was Yumiko
claimed she was born in Hong Kong
Tracing the email IP put her or them in southern, western Hong Kong, probably a server node I am not an expert just learning the hard way.
Host server Tracing [www.lginn.com](http://www.lginn.com) put it in Frankerurt Germany.
about 1 or 2 weeks later, they were jumping all over the USA with a VPN.

The thing to take from this, if you sense, see, read anything that doesn't seem correct. Simply just stop! And get your money back if at all possible.

In my case I noticed many things that were wrong but i didn't do anything about it except intrust my findings to a fake friend that was stealing everything from me. I had no PHYSICAL friend looking over my shoulder, to say "Hay! I feel uncomfortable about sending your money to this website." something is wrong with this!
or to even discuss anything fishy.

The Fact of the matter. I saw issues, bugs, and other problems and did nothing! and later realised I had no blockchain information access in Lginn.com It wasn't my wallet. "it was hers or there's!!!"
The entire site is there to trick you ,and the truth is you are playing with fake numbers, 12,000,000 usd fake numbers :'(
They had me occupied for 4 months, I tested withdrawals twice while having contact with that Asian girl was just to make you feel comfortable so you would invest more and more. after they thought you were all tapped out, they block you on "WhatsApp". and never getting any money back

in truth they stole 4 BTC, at the time was 1,550,000 Baht
or around 50,000 USD

Fool me once shame on you, fool me twice shame on me. NEVER AGAIN. I have lost a great deal of confidence in bitcoin and all other currencies. companies dealing with BTC should have some sort of government credentials that is registered with ID's Bank accounts say at least 5 different IDs and location: and have a government secure site to validate them, before sending and exchanging Bitcoin for your hard earned time.

Tf a girl try to get to invest, save yourself loss time and fake feelings and crying over lost fake money BLOCK THAT BITCH before they take you or every penny you worked hard for.

Remember this if nothing else... money = time spent making it.
if the steal your savings. which is all that time you struggled to save it.
and the stole the time from you in which you have to save it again.

don't waste your time for a piece of skank skirt you'll never meet and regret knowing and wish you had a time machine.
That goes for Ladies too! trust no one!!

Remember also those people never cared for you no matter what they said or say or do.
There is a 0.09 chance that i am wrong, BUT not a single person in the world that is honest cares and wants to help you with bitcoin, any dating site trading sites, chat and in my case another scam group I was pilfered from 99.91 % they only want to take your hard earned time in cash form.
don't talk to strangers

and for f*&k sake. coin wallet companies should have lists of known scammer wallets not only to block but to make their customers aware of scammer wallets numbers, and to provide self teaching information and maybe have a little exam to ensure they read and understood before continue to finish signing up for a wallet account.

And for those doing Scam baiting good luck on getting as much information as possible, turn it into an entertainment youtube channel in wasting scammers time and even getting convictions.

unfortunately I am not savvy enough to hack or understand java
Though after downloading the lginn.com website i found three files with 2 names and maybe a third name. Please note their code with their names could also be stolen.

- Matthieu Aussague, IT teacher in California also lived in France in think.
- Li Chang Other Coding No Face picture but plenty of coding examples by them on line
- Yumiko, I have seen her face only once, Hides her face in whatsapps photo, and am not sure if is the same girl. the whats app picture is of a slim asian, that looks to have a longer face that what i saw in real life well through video chat.
  To be honest she was not as good looking as I had imagined, she was slim looking with a small round face, that was heavily scared from acne I guess, (not a no oils vigan for sure) I only wished my samsung A50 wasn't a piece of S#1t and would that the F๒๕ษๅฌฏ screenshot! god i hate S#1t tech!

This is useful to see what's going on: https://www.cointracker.io/wallet/bitcoin and enter the address to see if there is any coins in it "low and behold mine in lginn says 0.00"
Acceptance of the loss is hard :'(
Again freaking useful tools that nobody knows about to help avoid scammers!

The whole system and knowledge shearing around Bitcoin needs to change to make it much harder for scammers to scam innocent people

Best of luck don't be another sistictic

John L